# gotoAndPlay + onEnterFrame not working flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a flash game, and gotoAndPlay not work with onEnterFrame function

Can someone help me?

```
movieclip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
function moveChar(event:Event):void
{
    if (rightKeyDown)
    {
        movieclip.gotoAndPlay("moving");
    }
}
```

I know, there is a way with "var" things but I dont want to use it.

Comment: I think you should turn on strict mode and look at your compiler errors to see why this is failing.

Comment: Where is rightKeyDown defined? In your comment in one of the answers you say it is constantly firing gotoAndPlay so you need to figure out why it is evaluating to true every time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will work:

```
movieclip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
function moveChar(event:Event):void
{
   if (rightKeyDown)
   {
       gotoAndPlay("moving");
   }
}
```

Comment: no, the problem is that Enter_Frame tries every second "gotoAndPlay" if you're pressing right button.

Comment: In this case, you should use KeyboardEvent